# identifier of instance was altered hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using hibernate i am getting identifier of instance was altered from x to y.
In my hbm file,data field is of type Long while in database table,column it is  int.
Can this be the problem?

Comment: Is this some error you are getting? What is the problem?

Comment: "identifier of instance was altered from x to y" is the error i am getting

Comment: There could be multiple root causes. Post your POJO class with hibernate mappings and the application code that is performing the db operation.

Comment: Post your stacktrace and code where you are getting this error.

Comment: ------POJO Class---
private Long Id;
public Long getId()
 { return Id; }
public void setId(Long Id)
 { this.Id = Id; }
----Employee.hbm.xml-----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.test.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true">
 <id name="Id" type="java.lang.Integer" unsaved-value="null">
   <column name="ID"  />
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id></class>
</hibernate-mapping>